# Auto update after specific day passed

Tags: php

Hey guys, i've this theme of the week script, easy, just post like normally, save in database and echo it in a column.

But since its theme of the week, i would like it to automatically renew the value to say "none" or "not set" after a week. I know cron jobs could do this but is there another way? [Running in PHP]

Comment: Please explain your situation in more detail. For example, what is "the value"?

Comment: that's wrong approach at all. The database way explained in the Kamil's answer. Just determine the day at select time

Comment: Relative to the server's time or the _user's_ time?

Comment: relative to the server's time (which i could set)

Answer (score 2):

Cron job would be the optimal solution but if you can't do that you could have your main page check if it's time to "renew" on every page load. It's a lot less efficient but it's an alternative if you don't have access to cron jobs.

Answer (score 1):

Add an expires column to the database and set it to now + 7days.  Default it to a date way in the future 9999-12-31 for Mysql.  Then select based on the expiry being > now.

As a side benifit you can easily implement theme of the day, month, season, year... etc.

Comment: I don't get this, there's actually a function within the database that does that?

Comment: Mysql has an adddate function that you can use to add intervals of various types.  Use the appropriate interval when adding a theme.  I believe you may be able to use it to default the theme to theme of the week. 

I notices a type in the select note.  It should read 'expires < now()'.

Answer (score 0):

You could keep it in the database along with the date of saving and determine if it expired by comparing that date plus one week with current date.